# Webpack with babel-loader for react corrupts image files

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, isomorphic-javascript

I am using webpack with babel-loader to transform .jsx react files.
However, adding a file-loader or style- and css-loader does not correctly process the images required() in the react components or style sheets.

They get recognized by webpack and copied to the dist folder. The path to the image file is correct, I've verified this in the css and js output.
The server is also able to display the files, I've checked with some manually copied ones.

What is happening is that the images themselves get corrupted. No image viewer nor the browser can display the image which results in an invisible image in the browser.

What I've tried so far:

- using only babel-loader as suggested in: https://github.com/webpack/file-loader/issues/35, results in Error: No handler for file type.
- using file-loader directly
- using image-webpack-loader (which seems to be using file-loader under the hood)
- using IsomorphicLoaderPlugin (https://github.com/jchip/isomorphic-loader)  which seems to be a simpler alternative to webpack-isomorphic-tools
- using css background-images with url() and ExtractTextPlugin('style-loader", 'css-loader')

All of the above steps resulted in either errors with webpack not finding an appropriate handler or corrupted image files.

Here is my current webpack config for reference (I've included all of it in case there are any problems/conflicts I am overlooking):

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin'),
        webpack = require('webpack');
        IsomorphicLoaderPlugin = require("isomorphic-loader/lib/webpack-plugin");



module.exports = {

    context: __dirname + '/client',

    entry: ['babel-polyfill', './index.jsx'],

    output: {
        filename: 'app.js',
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        publicPath: '/'
    },

    resolve: {
        ignore: /node_modules/,
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },

    devtool: 'source-map',

    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css'),

        new IsomorphicLoaderPlugin({ keepExistingConfig: false }),

        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            "process.env": {
                BROWSER: JSON.stringify(true)
            }
        })
    ],

    module: {

        preLoaders: [
            {
                loaders: ['isomorphine']
            }
        ],

        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                loader: 'babel',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    cacheDirectory: true,
                    plugins: ['transform-runtime', 'transform-decorators-legacy', 'transform-class-properties', 'transform-object-rest-spread'],
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader')
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
                loader: "file!isomorphic"
            }
        ]
    }
};
```